# PostGIS line in polygon performance (ST_Intersects)

Tags: postgis, spatial-join

I am running an analysis to find lines that is covered by a polygon. I have to create the polygon from a road network (hence the buffer and union) because the the lines are not exactly equal. The query works but it takes a long time to run, about 350 seconds on my dataset of about 20 000 buffered and united lines.

Is there a way I could modify it to make it execute faster?

```
with poly as  (
    SELECT ST_UNION(ST_BUFFER(lines.geom, 3)) as newgeom 
        FROM roads
)
select 
    case    
    when ST_coveredby(l.geom, poly.newgeom)
    then l.geom
    else
        ST_Intersection(geom, poly.newgeom) end as geom
from lines as l
    inner join poly
        on ST_Intersects(l.geom, poly.newgeom)
            and not ST_touches(l.geom, poly.newgeom)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this query would be faster and produce the same / equivalent results:

```
WITH temp AS (
SELECT 
    r.road_id,
    ST_Intersection(ST_Buffer(r.geom, 3), l.geom) AS newgeom
FROM lines l
    JOIN roads r
        ON ST_DWithin(l.geom, r.geom, 2.99) -- 2.99 instead of 3 to exclude geometries that only touch
)
SELECT
    road_id,
    ST_Union(newgeom) AS geom
FROM temp
GROUP BY road_id
;
```

This way the spatial join and the spatial filter would be done in the same step (using the *ST_DWithin* function) and making use of spatial indexes of both layers.

Comment: Thank you, that workeded great, loads faster. 1.1 seconds! The returned geometry was slightly different but did not change the end result.

Answer (score 3):

It is slow because there is no spatial index on the buffered geometries.

You could create a temporary table with a spatial index, populate it with the buffered geometries, and run the query on this temp table.